USB audio interface continuously connects and disconnects once audio output starts
I'm having issues getting my audio interface (Mackie DLZ Creator) working properly on my Linux machines. I've tried using both PulseAudio and Pipewire, although I've been focusing mostly on using Pipewire. I'm also having the same issues on both Debian and NixOS.
I'm seeing the device over USB, and when no audio is playing I see the sources and sinks with wpctl status:
> wpctl status    
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [1.0.1]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      48. Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [alsa]
 │      50. Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller  [alsa]
 │      94. DLZ Creator                         [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │      38. Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo [vol: 0.35]
 │  *   49. DLZ Creator Analog Surround 4.0     [vol: 0.53]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │      54. Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo [vol: 0.26]
 │  *   68. DLZ Creator Multichannel            [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Node Names:
         0. Audio/Sink    alsa_output.usb-LOUD_Audio__LLC_DLZ_Creator_no_serial_number-00.analog-surround-40
         1. Audio/Source  alsa_input.usb-LOUD_Audio__LLC_DLZ_Creator_no_serial_number-00.multichannel-input

I've also set the DLZ Creator as the default source and sink. However, once I start playing some audio, the output comes through my laptop speakers instead of the DLZ Creator. I can also see the DLZ Creator appearing and disappearing from the list of devices over and over again while the audio is playing.
journalctl shows this batch of logs happening over and over:
Jun 18 12:56:39 kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
Jun 18 12:56:40 kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a73, idProduct=0033, bcdDevice= 1.30
Jun 18 12:56:40 kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 18 12:56:40 kernel: usb 1-1: Product: DLZ Creator
Jun 18 12:56:40 kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: LOUD Audio, LLC
Jun 18 12:56:40 kernel: usb 1-1: SerialNumber: no serial number
Jun 18 12:56:40 kernel: usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 19
Jun 18 12:56:40 pipewire[1706]: spa.alsa: surround40:4p: snd_pcm_drop: No such device
Jun 18 12:56:40 pipewire[1706]: spa.alsa: surround40:4p: close failed: No such device

dmesg shows similarly repeating logs:
[57648.041528] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 124 using xhci_hcd
[57648.172355] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a73, idProduct=0033, bcdDevice= 1.30
[57648.172365] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[57648.172371] usb 1-1: Product: DLZ Creator
[57648.172375] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: LOUD Audio, LLC
[57648.172378] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: no serial number
[57667.052179] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 124

I've done a lot of troubleshooting focusing on what cables and ports I'm using, and once I pulled out an old Mac to double check that cables are working properly, I discovered strange: The DLZ Creator works properly if I plug it into the Mac first and then plug it into a Linux machine without turning the DLZ off/on in between. However, if I turn on the DLZ and it is already connected to the Linux box, it exhibits the disconnect/connect loop when I begin playing any audio. Doing a round trip to the Mac and back with the USB cable fixes it. This is all using the same cables and ports.
Does anyone have advice about what to try?

Sounds like a power problem. How many USB devices are plugged in to your computer? Try connecting through a Powered USB Hub.

@waltinator The DLZ Creator has its own power supply, it isn't powered via USB.
